# Repeat in range with itertools.product

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to repeat in range with `itertools.product` with this code:

```
            minLength=InputInt(" Please Enter the Min Length of Your Word : ")
            maxLength=InputInt(" Please Enter the Max Length of Your Word : ")
            characters=input(" Please Enter the Character of Your Word : ")

            res = itertools.product(characters, repeat=range(minLength,maxLength)) 
            for i in res: 
                    print(' Password Created : ',''.join(i), end='\r',flush=True)
```

but when I use this code `repeat=range(minLength,maxLength)` it shows me this error:

> res = itertools.product(characters, repeat=range(minLength,maxLength))
>   TypeError: 'range' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

**What's the problem? How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Is that code supposed to print 1 password? Or do you want it to print every possible product of those characters with a length in the requested range?

Comment: @PM2Ring I would like to print this product to any possible product of these characters in length in the requested range

Comment: So if someone enters 8 for the min & max lengths, and "ABCDEFGHIJ" for the characters, you want the program to print 100 million strings.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes . it only way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, use:

```
res = [x for i in range(minLength,maxLength) for x in itertools.product(characters, repeat=i)]
```